# How to : Set background color of Text with Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am messing around with swift UI and while creating a view I cannot figure out how to make the text I added to the view have the same background color as the view itself. StrokeText() keeps a white background when apart of the view below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
               HStack {
                   VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    StrokeText(text: "App Name", width: 1.0, color: .black)
                        .background(Color.init(hue: 0.2722, saturation: 0.89, brightness: 0.29, opacity: 1.0))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold))
                    
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)

                    //Background Color
                          Color.init(hue: 0.2722, saturation: 0.89, brightness: 0.29, opacity: 1.0).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                 
                       }
                   }
               }
      
    }
}

struct StrokeText: View {
    let text: String
    let width: CGFloat
    let color: Color

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            ZStack{
                Text(text).offset(x:  width, y:  width)
                Text(text).offset(x: -width, y: -width)
                Text(text).offset(x: -width, y:  width)
                Text(text).offset(x:  width, y: -width)
               
            }
            .foregroundColor(color)
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here is a picture for reference

[image: app issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what is your desired final effect but if you just want the green background on the label to go edge to edge just move the background modifier under the frame:

```
StrokeText(text: "App Name", width: 1.0, color: .black)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        .background(Color.init(hue: 0.2722, saturation: 0.89, brightness: 0.29, opacity: 1.0))
```